# Convert jQuery Script to plan JS for bootstrap nav bar drop down collapse on top of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I'm trying to convert a jQuery script to pure JS. This script is to fix an issue on a site of mine were I have a nav bar with drop downs with an `iframe` on the rest of the screen.

Without this script the downdowns don't collapse when anywhere in the `iframe` is clicked. The jQuery works but I cant get the JS only working and don't know much about JS

```
$(window).on("blur", function() {
  $(".dropdown").removeClass("show"), 
  $(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("show"),
  $(".dropdown-toggle").attr("aria-expanded", !1).focus()
});
```

```js
window.blur(), 
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown').classList.remove('show'), 
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu').classList.remove('show'), 
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle').getAttribute("aria-expanded", !1).focus;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the html, so it's not as easy to answer this question.

### ES6 way

```js
window.onblur = () => {
  const
    removeClass = (el, className) => el.classList.remove(className),
    dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown'),
    menus = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu'),
    togglers = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')

  for (const d of dropdowns) removeClass(d, 'show')
  for (const m of menus) removeClass(m, 'show')
  for (const t of togglers) t.getAttribute('aria-expanded', false).focus
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown.show {
  display: initial;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true">
  toggler
</div>
<div class="dropdown show">
  <div class="dropdown-menu show">
    menu
  </div>
</div>
```

### Old way

```
window.onblur = function () {
  function removeClass(el, className) {
    el.classList.remove(className)
  }

  // When calling `getElementsByClassName, you get collection of elements
  // So you can't call `classList` method on it
  var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')
  var menus = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu')
  var togglers = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')

  // You have to iterate over found elements
  for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) removeClass(dropdowns[i], 'show')
  for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) removeClass(menus[i], 'show')
  for (var i = 0; i < togglers.length; i++) togglers[i].getAttribute('aria-expanded', false).focus
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix one slight issue if you click the same drop down after closing it that it won't reopen unless you click a different drop down and then go back to the original drop down